# Need help understanding API and LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq

I'm trying to set up an API for a system I'm working on, but the LINQ seems to not grab the parameters.

A bit of background: During covid I've been working with a local business owner to develop an info system for his business. So far, everything has been kept in the browser, but now we want to create  a small windows form application the users can download instead of using the browser. The application will be much smaller in scope than the full site, but I don't want the SQL connection in the form.

So I guess my first question is, am I being overly cautious at not wanting the SQL connector in the client and wanting them to connect to the database, via an API, or is it safe enough to add the connection and calls directly in the application (I know how to do this, it's the API part I can't figure out). I'm thinking about it from a security point of view - would the users be able to find the connection and potentially do harm to my database by having it straight in the application or is it safe there?

If using API calls is the proper way to go, that leads me to my second question. How do I configure it properly?

This is my table (I've been following the Microsoft ToDoItems tutorials):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TodoItems] (
    [Id] [int] identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [IsComplete] [bit] NULL,
    [Secret] [nvarchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

My test form has a single button, which when pressed calls this method:

```
static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            // Update port # in the following line.
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7217/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            try
            {
                // Create a new product
                TodoItem product = new TodoItem
                {
                    Name = "Gizmo",
                    IsComplete = false,
                    Secret = "false"
                };

                var url = await CreateProductAsync(product);
                Console.WriteLine($"Created at {url}");

                // Get the product
                product = await GetProductAsync(url.PathAndQuery);
                ShowProduct(product);

                // Update the product
                Console.WriteLine("Updating IsCompleted...");
                product.IsComplete = true;
                await UpdateProductAsync(product);

                // Get the updated product
                product = await GetProductAsync(url.PathAndQuery);
                ShowProduct(product);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

My ToDoItem class looks like this:

```
public class TodoItem
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
        public string Secret { get; set; }
    }
```

My first issue is creating the ToDoItem. This method should do the trick:

```
static async Task<Uri> CreateProductAsync(TodoItem product)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(
                "api/todoitems", product);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // return URI of the created resource.
            return response.Headers.Location;
        }
```

However, when I run the method my API logs this error and nothing is posted to the database:

```
Executed DbCommand (46ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = Boolean), @p1='?' (Size = 4000), @p2='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      INSERT INTO [TodoItems] ([IsComplete], [Name], [Secret])
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2);
      SELECT [Id]
      FROM [TodoItems]
      WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity();
```

The way I read this, and I might be wrong, the method CreateProductAsync (which gets a product with the values "Gizmo", false and "false") simply doesn't transfer the values to the API.

For reference, my API ToDoContext class look like this:

```
public class TodoContext : DbContext
    {
        public TodoContext(DbContextOptions<TodoContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

Do I need to add something to this class? I'm wholly unfamiliar with both API and LINQ, but I did figure out that changing the table name to ToDoItems made the connection for me on its own.

Comment: It didn't log an error. That's not an error, that's just the command it ran to insert the data into the database. And if you were to suspect that your API isn't receiving values from the client, then you should either log what it receives or [leverage your IDE's debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022) to see what's going on.

Comment: Anything you put in an app that you deliver to an end user is something they can inspect and see the internals of. So if you don't want them to directly connect to your DB, then don't expose your database over the network to them, and don't design your app in a way that forces you to hand them a connection string. Yes, using an API exposed over the Internet is often a pattern, and then that API should have sufficient authentication, authorization, and rate limiting to keep it from being abused.